# Display of "Not visible individually" for a simple product in mini cart in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I want to display `not visible individually` simple products in the mini cart section.

This product displays inside the cart page, but it doesn't display inside the top minicart section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override

> magento2\vendor\magento\module-checkout\CustomerData\Cart.php

Find getRecentItems() function replace

```
if (!isset($products[$productId])) {
    continue;
}
```

with

```
if (!isset($products[$productId])) {   
    $items[] =  $this->itemPoolInterface->getItemData($item);  
    continue;
  }
```

Please let me know above code not work.

Comment: We need to add sequence node in module.xml for Magento_Checkout module, and update in di.xml for our module Cart.php is required else it will throw errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can override customerdata using file di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart"
                 type="Namespace\Module\CustomerData\Cart" />
</config>
```

You can override the function inside the `Namespace\Module\CustomerData\Cart.php` file. Just create the file `Cart.php` inside the `Namespace\Module\CustomerData` folder.

```
namespace My\Module\CustomerData;

use Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionSourceInterface;

/**
 * Cart source
 */
class Cart extends \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSectionData()
    {
        $totals = $this->getQuote()->getTotals();
        return [
            'summary_count' => $this->getSummaryCount(),
            'subtotal' => isset($totals['subtotal'])
                ? $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($totals['subtotal']->getValue())
                : 0,
            'possible_onepage_checkout' => $this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout(),
            'items' => $this->getRecentItems(),
            'extra_actions' => $this->layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons')->toHtml(),
            'isGuestCheckoutAllowed' => $this->isGuestCheckoutAllowed(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get active quote
     *
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote
     */
    protected function getQuote()
    {
        if (null === $this->quote) {
            $this->quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
        }
        return $this->quote;
    }

    /**
     * Get shopping cart items qty based on configuration (summary qty or items qty)
     *
     * @return int|float
     */
    protected function getSummaryCount()
    {
        if (!$this->summeryCount) {
            $this->summeryCount = $this->checkoutCart->getSummaryQty() ?: 0;
        }
        return $this->summeryCount;
    }

    /**
     * Check if one page checkout is available
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isPossibleOnepageCheckout()
    {
        return $this->checkoutHelper->canOnepageCheckout() && !$this->getQuote()->getHasError();
    }

    /**
     * Get array of last added items
     *
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item[]
     */
    protected function getRecentItems()
    {
        $items = [];
        if (!$this->getSummaryCount()) {
            return $items;
        }

        foreach (array_reverse($this->getAllQuoteItems()) as $item) {

           /* if (!$item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()) {
                $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
                $products = $this->catalogUrl->getRewriteByProductStore([$productId => $item->getStoreId()]);
                if (!isset($products[$productId])) {
                    continue;
                }
                $urlDataObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($products[$productId]);
                $item->getProduct()->setUrlDataObject($urlDataObject);
            }*/
            $items[] = $this->itemPoolInterface->getItemData($item);
        }
        return $items;
    }

    /**
     * Return customer quote items
     *
     * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item[]
     */
    protected function getAllQuoteItems()
    {
        if ($this->getCustomQuote()) {
            return $this->getCustomQuote()->getAllItems();
        }
        return $this->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    }

    /**
     * Check if guest checkout is allowed
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isGuestCheckoutAllowed()
    {
        return $this->checkoutHelper->isAllowedGuestCheckout($this->checkoutSession->getQuote());
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u very much @rakesh ji its working