# Override do not apply in a custom module

Tags: magento2, module, overrides, custom, di

I try to override the mini cart but by changes are not getting applied. I have the following in my `di.xml` inside custom module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart" type="Vendor\Custom\CustomerData\Cart" />
    <preference for="Magento\Tax\CustomerData\CheckoutTotalsJsLayoutDataProvider" type="Vendor\Custom\CustomerData\CheckoutTotalsJsLayoutDataProvider" />
</config>
```

and I override for example

```
public function getSectionData()
    { var_dump('test'); die;}
```

the structure what I was building is the same what I was created here [How to override magento-checkout CustomerData/Cart.php?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113511/how-to-override-magento-checkout-customerdata-cart-php)

but never gets executed!

Comment: Did you enable your extension? i.e. `registration.php`, `module.xml`, `php bin/magento module:enable xyz`, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the Plugins concept? As far as I know plugins are the first thing to consider when extending core functionality is required, but if it is not suitable for you remember after adding some preferences running the setup:di:compile shell command

Comment: so I was running setup:di:compile but without result!