# How to override getSectionData() method of magento-checkout CustomerData/Cart.php?

Tags: magento2, module, overrides, mini-cart, plugin

Is it possible to overwrite "`public function getSectionData()`" of class m`agento-checkout/CustomerData/Cart.php` only with the help of Plugin

My di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<!--    <type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\AbstractItem">
    <plugin name="AddAttPlug" type="Trimantra\ShippingMessage\Plugin\DefaultItem" disabled="false" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>-->
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart">
    <plugin name="AddMsgPlug" type="Trimantra\ShippingMessage\Plugin\Cart" disabled="false" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

My class file

```
    <?php

namespace Trimantra\ShippingMessage\Plugin;

class Cart 
{
    public function afterGetSectionData(\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData $subject, $result)
    {

    ......
    return  $result;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please Share in question that what have you tried

Comment: I want to add some extra html with dynamic data based on quote in content.html file of minicart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare the following in your module `etc/di.xml` :

```
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart">
        <plugin name="my-custom-plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CustomerData" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Then in your `Vendor\Module\Plugin\CustomerData.php` you can write:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class CustomerData {

    public method afterGetSectionData(\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart $subject, $result)
    {
        // Get the previous data
        $data = $result;
        // Append variable
        $data .= "test";
        return $data;
    }
}
```

NB: you can also write an `aroundGetSectionData` and a `beforeGetSectionData` based on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also want to get all previous data return by "getSectionData" and need to append my variable in that. So how we get previous return data of that method ?

Comment: @AshishJagnani see my edited answer

Comment: after adding parameter in "afterGetSectionData" getting this error
{"message":"Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Vendor\\Module\\Plugin\\Cart::afterGetSectionData
() must be an instance of Magento\\Checkout\\CustomerData, instance of Magento\\Checkout\\CustomerData
\\Cart\\Interceptor given, called in \/var\/www\/html\/suayu_live\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception
\/Interceptor.php on line 150 and defined in \/var\/www\/html\/suayu_live\/app\/code\/Trimantra\/ShippingMessage
\/Plugin\/Cart.php on line 7"}

Comment: @AshishJagnani my bad I forgot the important part see my edit: http://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/134886/revisions

Comment: how can i access test variable in minicart?

Answer (score 1):

We can do this via Plugin, an sample Plugin from Magento default:

*vendor/magento/module-tax/etc/di.xml*

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart">
        <plugin name="cart_private_data_tax" type="Magento\Tax\Plugin\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart"/>
    </type>
```

*vendor/magento/module-tax/Plugin/Checkout/CustomerData/Cart.php*

```
public function afterGetSectionData(\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart $subject, $result)
{
  ......
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also want to get all previous data return by "getSectionData" and need to append my variable in that. So how we get previous return data of that method ?